# ¿Cómo cargar un proyecto node js a un host?

Tags: nodejs, hosting

Estoy aprendiendo **node js** pero mi duda surge cuando intento publicar dicho proyecto a un host no me ejecuta la aplicación.

Necesito ejecutar el archivo server.js para que me corra la app en dicho puerto, pero esto solo me funciona en local, ¿cómo lo hago desde un host?

Comment: mirate esto: http://pm2.keymetrics.io

Comment: El host debería tener alguna guía de ayuda para hacer eso que comentas, en especial si es para nodejs. Por lo común, tienes acceso por consola y desde ahí ejecutas comandos

Comment: puedes usar heroku https://www.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

No se si con host se refiere a a un servidor alojado en la nube, tampoco cual proveedor están usando, pero en el caso de amazon con EC2, se usan las instancias. Se pueden crear con el sistema operativo deseado, pero en el caso de seleccionar Ubuntu puede seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Crear la instancia.
2. Configurar las reglas de entrada y salida para habilitar los puertos 80, 443 que son http y https respectivamente.
3. Instalar Node js en la instancia.
4. Instalar pm2.
5. Instalar Nginx.
6. Pasar los archivos del proyecto al servidor, puede ser mediante git.

con PM2 se puede dejar corriendo el aplicativo en el puerto deseado por ejemplo el 3000, con nginx se redirige el trafico del puerto 80 a dicho puerto.